# Copying text from pidgin doesn't seem to make it onto the clipboard in Windows 7

Tags: clipboard, pidgin, gtk, gtk-windows

Copying text from pidgin using ctrl+c or right click and copy doesn't seem to make it onto the clipboard in Windows 7.
Has anyone else experienced this?
I'm using pidgin 2.7.9, but it's been occurring for awhile now.
Is it because of gtk? Is there an option somewhere I need to check for clipboard communications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the problem persist if you try to copy with CTRL-Insert, and paste using Shift-Insert? I think this is a GTK+-problem. [This support ticket](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/9200) (although it's old) suggests there might be a problem with later versions of GTK+ running on certain versions of Windows.

I suggest you try to install a couple of different versions of GTK+ and see if the problem persists. If I recall correctly, you can do that while keeping the same version of Pidgin installed.

Comment: Ahhah! You rock, thanks so much! The problem went away using ctrl-insert